# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2018-08-24T��:��:��" is malformed at "��:��:��"

Tags: java, jodatime

The front end is sending the date with an invalid time format and I get this exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format:
>   "2018-08-24T��:��:��" is malformed at "��:��:��"  at
>   org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket.doParseMillis(DateTimeParserBucket.java:187)
>     at
>   org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseMillis(DateTimeFormatter.java:826)
>     at
>   org.joda.time.convert.StringConverter.getInstantMillis(StringConverter.java:65)
>     at org.joda.time.base.BaseDateTime.(BaseDateTime.java:173)
>   at org.joda.time.DateTime.(DateTime.java:257)

Basically I want to check if the timestamp has any malformed data. If yes, I want to set it to 0. For example the datetime is `2018-08-24T��:��:��` I want to set it to `2018-08-24T00:00:00`

Comment: pls send your code, the we can help you better

Comment: In case of a exception during parsing, use substring and only parse the date, then set the time to 0.

Comment: @Donatic That isn't really required here. You can answer this nicely *without* looking at the code that throws, or at the data that comes in. This question has **all** relevant information, and honestly: the downvotes are misplaced here!

Comment: @GhostCat i totally agree, that the downvotes are missplace ( i did never downvote this question)

Comment: @Donatic And it seems the brave anonymous downvoters are still around, regarding what happened to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already half-way there.

```
try {
 .. your code that parses the FED input
} catch ( IllegalArgumentException e) {
 .. do further checking
```

Meaning: that exception is already giving you, well, an exception, when you received bad input from your source. In that case, you could a simply substring() or regex check on the incoming string. And if it goes "4digits dash 2 digits dash 2 digits" ... then you got a date, and can create a corresponding object manually, and fill in the time values to all 0 for example.

Comment: Yep. I also thought the same!!

Comment: I very much appreciate the quick comeback. Lets hope some more people understand that there is actually no reason to downvote your input.